# When does the sheaf property w.r.t proper maps hold?

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

A set-function between spaces is *proper* if pulls back compacts to compacts, *closed* if it pushes closed sets to closed sets, and *universally closed* if all its pullbacks are closed.

I am wondering if and when continuous functions glue along (continuous) surjective proper maps and/or (continuous) surjective universally closed maps. Specifically, I am wondering when the diagram $$\mathrm h_Z(Y)\to \mathrm h_Z(X)\rightrightarrows \mathrm h_Z (X\times _Y X)$$ induced from the kernel pair diagram of $f:X\to Y$
 is an equalizer diagram given that $f$ is (continuous and) proper and/or (continuous and) universally closed.

(Here $\mathrm h_Z=\mathrm{Hom}(-,Z):\mathsf{Top}^\text{op}\to \mathsf{Set}$.)